# How can I model this class in a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq, uml

I need a little of help. This is my design to organize several categories.

```
   Category 1
     Sub Category 1.1
       Sub Category 1.1.1
     Sub Category 1.2
     Sub Category 1.3
```

It would be a collection. I want to store it in a database, but I don't know how can I model it in a database table. I'm using SQL Server CE.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I forgot put the objective number in the class (1.1, 1.1.1).

Comment: Can you provide the columns that will be associated with the Category, SubCategory ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have a table something like this:

- category

  - id (primary key, not null)
  - name (text, not null)
  - parent_category_id (foreign key to category.id, nullable)

Then, if a category has a parent, you reference the `id` of that other row.  So the table is self-referential.  Toplevel categories have a null `parent_category_id`.

When building tables like this you do need to be careful that you don't create a circular reference.

Comment: Is that enough to get the objective numbers, right? I mean, 1.1, 1.1.1

Comment: No, you would also need some kind of "rank" column to indicate how to sort the category with respect to the other categories under the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can have a table where an item can reference its parent, if any.

[image]

If the `ParentId` column is `NULL`, the category is a root one. If not, the parent is referenced.

You can then find the subcategories of a category by walking through the table and searching for items with `ParentId` equal to `Id` of the category.

Note that `ParentId` must be indexed for better performance, and that there must be a foreign key of `ParentId` to `Id` to ensure the validity of your data.

Storing recursively the categories:

```
private void SaveCategoryRecursively(Category category)
{
    foreach (var subCategory in category.SubCategories)
    {
        query(@"
insert into [dbo].[Categories] ([Id], [ParentId], ...)
values (@id, @parentId, ...)", ...);
        this.SaveCategoryRecursively(subCategory);
    }
}

public void SaveCategories(IEnumerable<Category> rootCategories)
{
    foreach (var category in rootCategories)
    {
        query(@"
insert into [dbo].[Categories] ([Id], [ParentId], ...)
values (@id, NULL, ...)", ...);
        this.SaveCategoryRecursively(category);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple [Recursive Relation](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php).  Each Category should have a unique ID (primary key) and an optional field specifying its parent, which would be a foreign key mapping back to the same table.  Categories with a `NULL` parent are top-level categories.

The page I linked to also has information on how you can query this structure to find top-level or mid-level Categories.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my recommendation. Create Three tables. I am assuming that each table has different columns

```
Category { Id, Name,...} 
SubCategory {Id, Name, ..., **ParentID**}  [ParentID is a FK from Category table Id Column] 
SubSubCategory {Id, Name, ...,  **SubParentID**}  [SubParentID is a FK from SubCategory table ParentID Column]
```

Comment: This violates the [Zero One Infinity principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_One_Infinity)  See other answers for better solutions.