# Can you tell me some ways for this model in UI WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

I was doing this design:

[How can I model this class in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072819/how-can-i-model-this-class-in-a-database/7072841#7072841)

But I'm doing that in WPF. I'm a bit confused about how to create an interface WPF to add the objectives. I mean, only the interface (program design) to model the link problem.

RESULT:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Objective}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objectives}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: You mean the foreign key issue?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean, I'm gonna create categories and sub categories in the program. I plan to deal with data Grid control and several dataGridDetails. I want to hear some ideas to do a good interface or UI design in WPF. Do I make myself clear?

Comment: Maybe others think use treeView is better

Comment: A `TreeView` control with a custom `ItemContainerStyle` would most likely be the easiest solution. However, if you wanted to be able to edit the data inline, you could also try to implement a [TreeListView](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=treelistview&num=100&hl=en&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=MP1JTuf6BYyHrAew4ZGEBw&ved=0CGMQsAQ&biw=1680&bih=914) like control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate as follows (taken from [Here](http://www.dev102.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-use-hierarchical-datatemplate-in.html)):

```
 public class WebPage
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public List<WebPage> LinksInPage { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<WebPage> WebPages { get; set; }
}


    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Root}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WebPages}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:WebPage}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LinksInPage}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}"></TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this example has help me to get it

Comment: Please, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082488/how-can-i-get-the-node-level-in-a-treeview

Comment: How could I help there - there are couple of answers, which seems in the right direction. Are you looking on a way to set the Rank string directly from XAML?